# Saving an NSTableView selection in NSDocument using bindings

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, cocoa-bindings, nsdocument

I have the following set-up:

an NSTableView bound to an ArrayController for both Content and SelectionIndexes

the ArrayController's SelectionIndexes are bound to an NSIndexSet property in my NSDocument subclass.

All works fine, selection gets stored in NSDocument, when saving the NSDocument the write method gets called.

However on loading I have an issue: When loading the NSDocument the selectionIndexes property is correctly filled, but then the nib file gets loaded (makeWindowControllers) and in [NSWindowController setDocument] my selectionIndexes are replaced by a selectionIndexes NSSet that just selects the first item in my NSTableView (I suppose the default selection of the NSTableView).

How can I avoid this?